# Unable to run applications on iOS 13.5.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I am facing a strange issue with iOS 13.5.1 and Xcode Version 11.5 (11E608c) (Updated today). Whenever I try to run a app via Xcode, it gives the following error:

> iPhone is not available. Please reconnect the device.

[image: Please check the snapshot.]

I can see that the device is recognized and listed in Xcode devices menu. How can I fix this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Getting same error. Any solution?

Comment: I've got iOS 13.5.1 on my iPhone and Xcode Version 11.5 (11E608c) and running on the device works fine for me. Please try all the usual workarounds: restart the computer, restart the device, make sure you've gone through the "configure for debugging" routine in the Devices window, and so on.

Comment: I noticed my Xcode was not updated to 11.5, so I did that and then later restarted the xcode and device as well and then it worked